# Can't scroll and buttons get covered by animation after use of JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, 3d, cloud

I wanted to use this [3D clouds](http://cssdeck.com/labs/css-3d-clouds) in my Bootstrap Header, but after using the code, I can't scroll anymore and also the buttons & text get covered with the animation if the mouse is on certain positions on the screen.

I have then deactivated all functions, which relate to the mouse, but it still doesn't work properly.

Here is a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/saitam/rmctk7g0/) of it.
If you delete the html comment and use the following tags, then you are using the JS Animation and the complete highlight box is hidden by it.

```
<div id="viewport" >
    <div id="world" ></div>
</div>
```

Is there a possibility to put it into a container or a row?

Comment: Do you want to keep the "mousemove" functionality?

Answer (score 0):

To fix the scroll problem, comment / delete this:

```
body {
    ...
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

To fix the overlay problem, assign a z-index to your layer:

```
#viewport {
    ...
    z-index: -100;
}
```

This should fix your problem.

Comment: With regards to the scroll issue, if you don't have enough text that makes it necessary to scroll, the page won't scroll, even after getting rid of `overflow: hidden`.

Comment: If you want I can show you in the JSFiddle in collaborate mode.

Comment: Set the viewport position and it will work (position:absolute)